# Use Vlook_up using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have four columns in my excel data file:

```
CUI      ICD9/10    Out      Lookup
C0161894    39      4000001 C0000005
C0029730    398     4000002 C0000039
C0176693    398     4000003 C0000052
C0029730    3989    4000004 C0000074
```

I want to match 4th column from the 1st column and get 3rd column as the output using python. As the data is large so indirectly i want to use vLookups, but here i dont have any specific value. I need to search in whole column

Comment: So, you want to search for where the values in `Lookup` are equal to the values in `CUI`? Can you provide some code for how you are using this data in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to compare the values in column 4 and column 1, and if they are equal, output a new column with the value from column 3.

To do this, simply use `np.where` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CUI':['C0161894','C0029730','C0176693','C0029730','C0000074'],
                   'ICD9/10':[39,398,398,3989,3989],
                   'Out':[4000001,4000002,4000003,4000004,4000005],
                   'Lookup':['C0000005','C0000039','C0000052','C0000074','C0000074']})                       


df1['Match'] = np.where(df1.Lookup == df1.CUI,  df1.Out, 'No Match')
```

Output:

```
        CUI  ICD9/10    Lookup      Out     Match
0  C0161894       39  C0000005  4000001  No Match
1  C0029730      398  C0000039  4000002  No Match
2  C0176693      398  C0000052  4000003  No Match
3  C0029730     3989  C0000074  4000004  No Match
4  C0000074     3989  C0000074  4000005   4000005
```

Edit:

In response to your comment, you can use the `chunksize` parameter in `pandas.read_csv` to read in only parts of your dataframe:

For `data` in csv as follows:

```
     CUI  ICD9/10    Lookup      Out
C0161894       39  C0000005  4000001
C0029730      398  C0000039  4000002
C0176693      398  C0000052  4000003
C0029730     3989  C0000074  4000004
C0000074     3989  C0000074  4000005
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962187/2254228: You can do:

```
chunksize = 1000
for chunk in pd.read_csv(data, chunksize=chunksize):
    # process(chunk) using the solution above
    # Output Chunk to new csv using `pd.to_csv('new_data')`
```

Edit2: Here I have compiled full sample code for you. Replace the file `data` and `new_data` with whatever your data file is called and replace the file paths with your file paths. This will avoid any memory errors from your datafile being too big.

For some a sample `data.csv`:

```
     CUI  ICD9/10    Lookup      Out
C0161894       39  C0000005  4000001
C0029730      398  C0000039  4000002
C0176693      398  C0000052  4000003
C0029730     3989  C0000074  4000004
C0000074     3989  C0000074  4000005
```

Create a target csv file `new_data` as an empty csv file to store your new data frame:

```
CUI  ICD9/10    Lookup      Out
```

Then import the old data, splitting it into chunk, where chunksize = the number of lines of the file to read in:

```
# Read in line by line = set chunksize = 1
chunksize = 1

# Open New File
with open("Pathtonewfile/new_data.csv", "w") as f:

    # Iterate over the old data.csv file, reading in one line
    for chunk in pd.read_csv('Pathtooldfile/data.csv', index_col = False, chunksize=chunksize):

        # Carry out Lookup Calculation as above
        chunk['Match'] = np.where(chunk.Lookup == chunk.CUI,  chunk.Out, 'No Match')

        # Write the new dataframe chunk to "new_data.csv"
        chunk.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False, 
                     cols=['CUI','ICD9/10','Out','Lookup'],
                     mode = 'a')
```

This gives you an output in `new_data.csv` as follows:

```
        CUI  ICD9/10    Lookup      Out     Match
0  C0161894       39  C0000005  4000001  No Match
1  C0029730      398  C0000039  4000002  No Match
2  C0176693      398  C0000052  4000003  No Match
3  C0029730     3989  C0000074  4000004  No Match
4  C0000074     3989  C0000074  4000005   4000005
```

Comment: I know, but i have some 8 million rows, so it is not possible to make a dataframe, becuase intially i was using the same value

Comment: @RachitAgarwal Please see my edit. You can use the `chunksize` parameter in `pd.read_csv` to read in only a small amount of your data. Then you can process each chunk with the formula in my original answer, and save it to a new csv file, iterating through each chunk. Make sense?

Comment: @RachitAgarwal Please see my new edit - full code for you.